# Stuck in an update, how to get to where I was?

Tags: upgrade

I'm using the console to do an upgrade.
And before finishing, the console told me that it was going to update a specific file, and that I could go and update it, keep the old one, or press D to know what were the changes.

I've pressed D, and now I don't know how to get out of that window, and continue with the update.

I've tried all Fs (F1 to F12), esc, enter, backspace, tab, etc.

What should I do? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That window should be the output of `diff`, probably piped into `less` or a similar viewer and can be exited by pressing <kbd>q</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Press the <kbd>q</kbd> key (for Quit) to get out of that window.